# Tags on unanswered page do not correspond to actual questions shown

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow, tags, unanswered-questions

When I tried to show unanswered JavaScript questions not related to jQuery on SO, it showed on the right that it was showing questions tagged with "[javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) not [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)" ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/javascript+-jquery?tab=newest)).  However, both the number of questions and the actual questions shown do not correspond to the description given by the page.  Is this just me, or is this actually a bug?

[image: Bug with unanswered section using not term: javascript -jquery]

EDIT: doesn't just affect Stack Overflow ([example with Programmers.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/javascript+-jquery?tab=newest)):

[image: Programmers.SE issue]

EDIT 2: This does not affect the "or" operator - `[javascript] or [jquery]` [works fine](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/javascript+or+jquery?tab=newest).

Comment: Are you still getting the same behavior?

Comment: @AsheeshR I do, and it's not just caching, e.g. [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18297227/xulrunner-could-not-be-found-in-the-release-folder) appears on page 5 (a lot further by the time you read this) and it's never been tagged [tag:javascript].

Comment: Odd. [This works fine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript+-jquery?sort=unanswered&pagesize=15), and [this](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript+-jquery?sort=unanswered&pagesize=15). cc @Gilles

Comment: It seems like when I click on "Unanswered" section after a search, SO "forgets" about my search (meaning it returns *all* unanswered questions). In addition to that, the URL becomes http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered (tested on Firefox 23 on Win 8)

Comment: Though in view of the other sections (Tags, Users, Badges) I guess you're not supposed to be clicking on anything not under "Questions"

Comment: @OldCheckmark Same for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unanswered questions tab performs an `OR` with the tags, so what you are getting is `Javascript OR NOT jQuery` and not `Javascriot AND NOT jQuery`.

https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/javascript+-jquery

In order to get the second `AND` set you need to search by tag and then filter by unanswered:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript+-jquery?sort=unanswered

Comment: Well it's not _quite_ the same, but whatever. Maybe I'll put in a feature request.